# Visual Studio 2015 Singleton issue

Tags: c#

I have created ClassLibrary Project in VS2015.
Inside I have created Singleton class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Library
{
    public class PoolOfThreads
    {
        private static PoolOfThreads instance = new PoolOfThreads();

        public static PoolOfThreads Instance
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }

        private List<Thread> listOfThreads;
        private int maxThreads;

        public int MaxThreads
        {
            get { return maxThreads; }
            set { maxThreads = value; }
        }

        private PoolOfThreads()
        {
            listOfThreads = new List<Thread>();
        }


        /// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
        public Thread NewThread(ParameterizedThreadStart threadMethod)
        {
            FreeThreads();

            if (listOfThreads.Count < maxThreads)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(threadMethod);
                listOfThreads.Add(thread);
                return thread;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("No free threads...");
        }

        private void FreeThreads()
        {
            /*var freeThreads = listOfThreads.Select(thread => thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped) as List<Thread>;
            foreach (Thread thread in freeThreads)
                listOfThreads.Remove(thread);
            */
            listOfThreads.RemoveAll(thread => thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped || thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Aborted);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created also UnitTest Project.
I added the reference to Library and everything is working properly.
I can test my Singleton.

The problem is when I create Windows Form Appl.
Every project is in the same solution. I added the references.

```
    using Library;
    using System.Net;
    using CalkaRozproszona.Classes;

    namespace CalkaRozproszona
    {
        public partial class ServerApplication : Form
        {
            Server server;
            ListObservator listObservator;
            PoolOfThreads.Instance.MaxThreads = 10;
            //Library.PoolOfThreads.Instance.MaxThreads = 10;


            public ServerApplication()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
     }
```

I cannot acces to my singleto class PoolOfThreads.
[image].
As you can see VS sees the class.
But when I try to go into Instance property I get the error:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Include the property definition for PoolOfThreads.MaxThreads.

Comment: the first code snipped is either not copy-pasted properly, or it won't compile - it is missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: Most probably `MaxThreads` is not public

Comment: @Artiom that will generate another error saying "can not access member due to its protection level bla bla..." or something like that

Comment: MaxThreds is in the class - i didnt paste it on my post :)

Comment: Does it actually compile? Sometimes I find that visual studio gets a bit confused and claims something doesn't exist but when you compile it works fine. In these cases closing VS and reopening and reloading solution tend to get it happy again.

Comment: Strange thing: I can`t even get into PoolOfThreads.Instance....

Comment: A missing curly brace is a good reason for visual studio not to find a property

Comment: I cleaned solution and reubilded few tiemes... still doesn`t work

Comment: Have you perhaps got another class `PoolOfThreads` which doesnt have the `MaxThreads` property. ie, could you have moved this class to a library and forgotten to delete the original? What happens if you `navigateTo` the `PoolOfThreads` class that it does recognise?

Comment: put another `}` see one is missing, or edit your question so others wont nitpick that

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: I think the {} are OK becuase in Test project everything works corectly:

Comment: Ok, so how do the unit tests get an instance to test?  Does comparing the working test code to the failing code shown above yield any insight?

Comment: I moved the line: PoolOfThreads.Instance.MaxThreads = 10; into ServerApplication() method and it works but why it didnt work before?

Comment: Sh***t I am stupid :P to much coffee - Can not edit other object properties outside of class methods..... Sorry for the problem....

Comment: Ha! Good catch, since you noticed it (or posted) before anyone else :)

Answer (score -2):

You can assign it to a variable like this:

```
public partial class ServerApplication : Form
{
    Library.PoolOfThreads poolOfThreads = Library.PoolOfThreads.Instance;
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point of a Singleton. You could *assign* the instance to a variable, but your not *instantiating* anything.

Comment: @Jamiec he meant write fully qualified names